# Exception error message with incorrect line number

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, .net-2.0, gac

When an exception is thrown in an Asp.Net web page, an error message is displayed with the complete stack trace.

Example below:

> Stack Trace: 
>    IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. 
>   **MyNameSpace.SPAPP.ViewDetailsCodeBehind.LoadView()  +5112**
>   MyNameSpace.SPAPP.ViewDetailsCodeBehind.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +67
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +13
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +43
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +98
>   ... ...

The problem is that the Line number displayed does not correspond to the line in my code that originated the exception.
In the example above, the stack shows line number 5111, yet my code behind .cs file only has 250 lines!

The aspx page is stored in a SharePoint site and the Assembly with the code behind has been deployed to GAC. Also, I've compiled in Debug mode.
**Given the settings above, how can I find out what line in my code caused the Exception?**

*Clarification as pointed out by [strelokstrelok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2788/strelokstrelok):*

> In **Release mode** the number in front of the exception is NOT the line of code. Instead it's an offset to the native compiled code, which doesn't have any meaning to humans. More about this here: http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2005/01/24/963.aspx
>
> In **debug mode** the PDB file will automatically map the native code offset to your .cs line in code and the number displayed WILL be the corresponding line in code.

Comment: .. of course when it is a line number it says so explicitly : .....\Areas\Store\Models\CheckoutModel.cs:line 158

Comment: Man I wish someone had given instructions on how best to translate this back into line numbers. Why you would release an internal webapp without debug symbols is beyond my comprehension, whose gunna reverse engineer it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those numbers are NOT line numbers. In Release mode the stack trace contains the offsets into the native compiled code instead of line numbers. You can read some more about it here:
http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2005/01/24/963.aspx

The only way to get line numbers in a stack trace is if you built you code in debug mode with the PDB files available.

Answer (score 3):

Your code behind file is not the complete class, it's only a portion that is used when the class as a whole is compiled by ASP.NET. To find what is truly on that line, take a look at the compiled class / assembly using a tool like Reflector.

Comment: I might be wrong here but AFAIK, in ASP.Net the stack always gives you the correct line, however, in Asp.Net + SharePoint this doesn't seem to be the case.

Anyway, I use red-gate .Net reflector but I couldn't find anything that would help me identify the line of code that caused the exception.

Comment: This is incorrect. Those numbers are NOT line numbers and not even offsets into IL.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the running code is not what you see on your screen. Some mate might have refactored it for you. :)

Comment: remember to get the latest code from source control if you're in a team environment +1