# C# StackTrace not aligned with source code

Tags: c#, stack-trace

I've been using the C# StackTrace feature in relation to some SW testing.

I've seen that the StackTrace is not always 100% aligned with the source code. For example, line numbers might be a bit off. My best guess is this has to do with some compiler optimizations.

Does anyone have experience with this or a reference to some documentation mentioning this?

Also, does anyone know whether I might get into the same problems using [CallerFilePath] feature?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you've guessed, it'll be down to compiler optimizations, especially in release code.

Comment: Typically the debug symbols dont fill in when the symbols rent lodaded. If you "continue debugging anyways" you have to know which assemblies you ahve the the correct debug sybols for. If they dont match then I'm guessing you don't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception error message with incorrect line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492201/exception-error-message-with-incorrect-line-number)

Comment: Thank you. 

I'll have to try out if this actually works correctly in debug mode. Don't remember whether I might have used it in release mode. It could definitely be a reason.

Comment: There's definitely a difference. I can reproduce a difference where the stack trace is 1 line off when in release and not when in debug. So, for now, I'll assume that's the reason and get back.

Does this mean that you should not use track traces in release mode? How about logs etc. that could help you find bugs (in the release build)?

I'm asking because I've never seen this behavior in Java so I think there's a fundamental difference between how the two compilers/VMs work in this respect.

Comment: Do you know whether the same difference in debug vs. release mode could occur for [CallerFilePath]?